# Protect postgres database from slow queries

Tags: postgresql

I'm running a Django web site on Heroku, with the database hosted on RDS. There are some queries out there that take 10 to 15 seconds. Yesterday I got a lot of those and it overwhelmed the database. Write IOPS went above 700, CPU went to 90%, and connections went to 0. I'm upgrading the database as a way to deal with these queries and get them into cache. But I'm wondering if there is a way to protect the database from these instances? Like set a timeout and release the connection rather than keep trying to hang on to it?

Edit: do you think setting [CONN_MAX_AGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-CONN_MAX_AGE) in Django will help?
 Maybe set it to a low number like 30 seconds?

Comment: It would probably be better to try and optimise these queries, so they are not so slow.

Comment: I'm working on that but it requires quite a bit of refactoring. These queries are edge cases where a crawler is hitting all/page?974, then 975, etc.

Comment: As far as query timeouts go, you can set [statement_timeout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT) per connection, per cluster, per role/user, etc. Eg. `alter role your_user set statement_timeout = '8s';`, this would cancel any query by "your_user" if it took longer than 8 seconds to execute. If that's too broad of a stroke, and if you can identify the sessions that you'd like to apply that to, you can also set it in the connection (eg. in JDBC), or in your session like `set statement_timeout to '8s';`.

Comment: You can also limit the number of concurrent queries by a user: `ALTER ROLE your_user CONNECTION LIMIT 10;`. Docs on `CONNECTION LIMIT` can be found under [CREATE/ALTER ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html)